# JQuery: Showing an image when loaded succesfully and conflict with onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

I want to show images only when they are loaded successfully (some paths give 404).
Have following code, which works fine.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".complex-image").load(function(){
          $(this).show();
      });
    });
</script>
```

Now, one of the pages shows a google map, which sets:

```
onload = initMap
onunload = GUnload
```

On this page in IE8 and Chrome, image does *not* show up even when available. But shows up fine in Firefox 4. A sample page having image+map from my site is [this](http://operty.com/30078)

I have tried the inverse approach as well: hide images when there is error in loading. Using code below:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".complex-image").ready(function(){
          $(this).hide();
      });
    });
</script>
```

This does not hide images on IE8 both on map and non-map containing pages.

What is a cross-browser way to show images when loaded successfully, when there is a body onload defined?

Edit: Used Elzo's solution and to get img.load() fired even when image is getting read from cache, used this:
[jQuery callback on image load (even when the image is cached)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877027/jquery-callback-on-image-load-even-when-the-image-is-cached)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here is how to do it.](http://blog.valugi.ro/2009/09/11/callback-for-image-loading-with-jquery/) I put also a [demo](http://dev.valugi.ro/jquery/check-dynamic-loaded-image/).

Comment: I think another way is to check the image object is not null or undefined. Ok, it is not so beatuefil like your example, but it also should work.

Comment: Thanks! To get img.load() to fire even when image is getting read from cache, enhanced the solution using [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877027/jquery-callback-on-image-load-even-when-the-image-is-cached)